# Filtering TCPDUMP over packet length

Tags: tcpdump, multicast

I am looking to narrow down my `tcpdump` by packet length. I know I can `| grep  but I was wondering if I can pass this particular packet length as an option in 'tcpdump'. I am trying to write a script to show me all present MPEG-TS multicast on the network using the following command:

```
sudo tcpdump -c 1000 -ti <network_interface> multicast | grep 1316 | sort | uniq
```

So this command works and gives me exactly the output I want but I was thinking I could simplify it by passing the length in the `tcpdump` command, something like:

```
sudo tcpdump -c 1000 -ti <network_interface> multicast and length 1316 | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Total Ethernet packet size**

According to *pcap-filter(7)*, you can use the following conditions:

- `less length`, equivalent to `len <= length`
- `greater length`, equivalent to `len >= length`
- Based on the examples, you should also be able to use `len == length`, but that isn't documented.

Note that this includes the link-layer and network-layer headers (i.e. everything that was captured), so an empty TCP ACK will have an IP "total length" field of 60 but will be seen as 74 bytes total.

See also this StackOverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874093/how-to-filter-tcpdump-output-based-on-packet-length

**Total IP packet size**

According to *tcpdump(1)*, you can access the IPv4 header's "Total Length" field:

- `ip[2:2] > 576`
- `ip[2:2] <= 1000`
- and similar.

**Total UDP packet or payload size**

UDP doesn't have a length field, but its header size is always 8, and you can *usually* assume that the IPv4 header size will always be 20 (IPv4 options are *very* rare, although they do get used in IGMP).

So if you're trying to filter for 1316-byte UDP datagrams,

- IP.TotalLength = IP.Header[20] + UDP.Header[8] + UDP.Payload[1316]

you get the filter `ip[2:2] == 1344`.

Comment: apparently this option doesn't really work. The  output of this command 
`$ sudo tcpdump -c 100 -t multicast and greater 1345` is 
`IP 10.153.243.25.49152 > 225.0.0.0.4000: UDP, length 1316`

Comment: It works fine. Are you trying to filter by UDP length, IP length, Ethernet length? Are you including the header size or only the payload size? The packet you're showing is approximately 1358 bytes total (Eth[14] + IPv4[20] + UDP[8] + payload[1316]).

Comment: I am trying to limit by UDP payload size.